# Firefox add-on how to detect the location change is from launch firefox with parameter

Tags: firefox-addon-sdk

When launch Firefox from command line, we can pass a URL to let Firefox open it for us. We have an extension need to distinguish such location change from normal location change like typing a new URL, clicking link etc.

We implemented nsIWebProgressListener in our add-on, and want to distinguish in onLocationChange :

```
onLocationChange: function (aWebProgress, aRequest, aLocation, aFlags) {
```

There is difficulty to understand meaning of bits in the aRequest.loadFlag:

E.g. we get following loadFlag:
1. Firefox.exe "URL", 8192000, which is 0x7d0000
2. Navigate in address bar, 7929856, which is 0x790000
3. Back/Forward, 7933952, which is 0x791000

Will appreciate if you have information to share regarding understanding the bits.

Answer (score 0):

Looking around at http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/ident?i=loadFlags , I noticed that in its usage in the source code, I saw `loadFlags` compared to the constants of [nsIChannel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIChannel#Constants), [nsICachingChannel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsICachingChannel#Constants), and [nsIRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/NsIRequest#Constants).

(I wonder, however, whether registering an [`nsICommandLineHandler`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsICommandLineHandler) (see also [`nsICommandLine`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsICommandLine) and [Command Line](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Command_Line)) may let you listen in on the `-url` flag. FYI, I have been able to use the interface successfully in an SDK add-on (albeit with a custom flag), with a reusable module at https://github.com/brettz9/webappfind/blob/master/lib/commandLineHandlerComponent.js .)